# Extract SMD from Matchit into gtsummary

Tags: r, gtsummary, propensity-score-matching

i would like to extract the SMD values from MatchIt https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MatchIt/vignettes/assessing-balance.html#recommendations-for-balance-assessment

into a gt summary table

library("MatchIt")
library("gtsummary")

```
data("lalonde", package = "MatchIt")

#1:1 NN matching w/ replacement on a logistic regression PS
m.out <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + 
                   nodegree + re74 + re75, data = lalonde,
                 replace = TRUE)
m.out

summary(m.out)
```

Is there any option to extract the SMD values from the summary function? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by SMD? You can save the summary into a new object with `s <- summary(m.out)` and then use `View(s)` to dig through the generated list. If you want to extract the `Std. Mean Diff.` you can do so like that:

```r
summary(m.out)[["sum.all"]][, "Std. Mean Diff."]
#>    distance         age        educ   raceblack  racehispan   racewhite 
#>  1.79408605 -0.30944526  0.05496466  1.76154189 -0.34984254 -1.88186760 
#>     married    nodegree        re74        re75 
#> -0.82630927  0.24497023 -0.72108381 -0.29026291
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much JBGruber. That helped a lot. SMD is Std. Mean Diff. I followed your advise. Object "s" is now "type" numeric. Can i extract these values to an Excelsheet or word? That would be great

Comment: Probably it would make sense to export the whole table: `rio::export(summary(m.out)[["sum.all"]], "mout.xlsx")`

Answer (score 1):

You can create df of paired variable names and SMDs using @JBGruber answer, and then join them to the gt_summary table using `modify_table_body` (and don't forget to assign header using `modify_header`)

For example:

```
data("lalonde", package = "MatchIt")

#1:1 NN matching w/ replacement on a logistic regression PS
m.out <- matchit(treat ~ age + educ + race + married + 
                   nodegree + re74 + re75, data = lalonde,
                 replace = TRUE)

m.data <- match.data(m.out)
   
m.summary <- summary(m.out, un = FALSE)

smds <- as.data.frame(m.summary[["sum.matched"]][, "Std. Mean Diff."]) %>%
  rownames_to_column("variable")
colnames(smds)[2] <- "smd"

m.data %>%
  select(age,
         educ,
         married,
         treat
  ) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = treat) %>%
  modify_table_body(
    ~.x %>%
      left_join(
        smds,
        by = "variable"
      ) %>%
      mutate(smd = if_else(is.na(smd),"-",as.factor(round(smd, 2))))
  ) %>%
  modify_header(smd ~ "**SMD**")
```

will result in:
[image]

Fore more info see:

- https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/modify_table_body.html

I also used the first version of @Daniel D. Sjoberg answer here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68593396/revisions